# How to return data from nested models in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have four models for: countries > libraries > books > chapters. Each country has multiple libraries, which have multiple books consisting of multiple chapters.

With Laravel 5.8, how do I retrieve a list of all chapters of all books of all libraries of a specific country based on the slug?

**Country model:**

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function libraries() {
        return $this->hasMany(Library::class);
    }
}
```

**Library model:**

```
class Library extends Model
{
    public function country() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);//country_id
    }

    public function books() {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

**Book model:**

```
class Book extends Model
{    
    public function library() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Library::class);//library_id
    }

    public function chapters() {
        return $this->hasMany(Chapter::class);
    }
}
```

**Chapter model:**

```
class Chapter extends Model
{   
    public function book() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);//book_id
    }
}
```

I've been trying to retrieve the data as follows, without success:

**CountryController:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Country;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug)
    {    
        $country = Country::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $chapters = $country->with('libraries.books.chapters');
        dd($chapters);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }
}
```

Router:

```
Route::get('/countries/{slug}', 'CountryController@show');
```

I am not getting a specific, error, but the returned data does not exist. When I expand `#model` in the returned dump, I see `exists: false`, although eager loading seems to be correct.

```
Builder {#217 ▼
  #query: Builder {#213 ▶}
  #model: Country {#218 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: array:3 [▼
    "libraries" => Closure() {#221 ▶}
    "libraries.books" => Closure() {#224 ▶}
    "libraries.books.chapters" => Closure() {#220 ▶}
  ]
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:17 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Comment: You are not even fetching the records. Ex: `$chapters->get()`. Are you trying to get only the chapters or all intermediate models as well?

Comment: @Pablo ->get() throws an SQL error. Only trying to get the chapters.

Comment: Sharing the error would be helpful for sure :)

Comment: your problem can be fixed with "Has Many Through" : https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @HadiAghandeh Looked into this, but it doesn't go 4 levels deep.

Comment: @bart If fetching the records throws an error then your relations are not configured correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the outer most model. In this case the `Chapter`. So to get all chapters from books in X country you can use something like this:

```
Chapter::whereHas('book.library.country', function($q) use ($slug){
  $q->where('slug', $slug)
})
```

If you think how SQL queries are executed, from the inside out, then above query builder will make more sense. The query from closure will be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use query builder for this purpose:
I have not test this but it might work:

```
$chapters = DB::table('chapters')
        ->join('books', 'chapters.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
        ->join('libraries', 'books.library_id', '=', 'libraries.id')
        ->join('countries', 'libraries.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
        ->select('chapters.*')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the model to dictate the query and respect its relations/.